# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation

Tags: java, jpa

Cree una aplicacion en java que utiliza jpa y funciona correctamente. Luego cree un ejecutable con el Launch4j y posteriormente un instalador con Inno Setup. Instalo en la maquina donde hice el desarrollo y funciona. al querer instalarlo en otra maquina, la aplicacin corre, trae datos de la base, valida los ingresados, pero a la hora de grabar, arroja este error. Alguna idea de que puede ser. En algun momento supuse que faltaria alguna libreria, pero no se conectaria ni traeria datos si asi fuera.

muchas gracias

Comment: Si ya hiciste esta pregunta ¿por qué la repites?

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!